# Pentaho - searching xml file

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have xml file and I want check this file and in output print only this records where sourceColumn is not equal targetColumn.
Do you have any idea how I can do this in Pentaho?
It doesn't have to be a ready-made solution, but at least a concept of how I could approach it.

Example data in file:

```
<Column
             sourceColumn="Column1"
             targetColumn="COLUMN1"
/>
<Column
             sourceColumn="Column2"
             targetColumn=
/>
```

Comment: What is your output file format? .

Comment: output file format .txt